# How to visualize fhog (not HOG)

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction

My MATLAB code uses `fhog` (instead of Hog) to extract features. However, I want to visualize the HOG features used on the image patch. I know `extractHOGFeatures` or [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/hog.html) is used if we use `HOG` available in MATLAB. But how do I visualize `fhog`?

Since Piotr's Image & Video Toolbox (which has `fhog`) is widely used in MATLAB now and I frequently need it, it would be great if someone can tell me how to visualize `fhog` extracted features.

The code of fhog can be found at [here](https://pdollar.github.io/toolbox/channels/fhog.html):

The code snippet is as follows:

```
if features.hog,
    %HOG features, from Piotr's Toolbox
    x = double(fhog(single(im) / 255, cell_size,    features.hog_orientations));
    x(:,:,end) = [];  %remove all-zeros channel ("truncation feature")
end

if features.gray,
    %gray-level (scalar feature)
    x = double(im) / 255;

    x = x - mean(x(:));
end
```

Edit: `hogDraw` [exists](https://github.com/pdollar/toolbox/blob/master/channels/hogDraw.m) but writing the following:

```
V = hogDraw(features, [cell_size], [fhog]);
```

gives me an error :

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fhog (line 70)
[M,O]=gradientMex('gradientMag',I,0,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work. It was a stupid thing I was ignoring.

```
For V = hogDraw(features, [cell_size], [fhog]);
```

write:

```
V = hogDraw(x, [cell_size], 1);
```

where 1 implies hog is set to be true.

To plot, do `plot(V)`